# How to focus click on input vue

Tags: vue.js, input, vuejs2, html-input

how do i focus input with a button onClick?

```
<div class="form-group"
v-for="(file, i) in registerData.requiredDocuments"
:key="`file-${i}`">
   <label for="npwp" class="text-muted"> {{file.name}} </label>
   <input type="file"
   :name="file.name"
   class="form-control-file"
   :id="file.name"
   :accept="file.name === 'Logo' ? `image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg` : `application/pdf`">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Choose File</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

i was hoping by clicking the 'choose file' button it would trigger the input. I've tried

```
// the input

<input :ref="file.name" type="file">

// the button 

<button @click="$refs.file.name.focus()">Choose File</button>
```

but what i get is the name is undefined anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem before, Here is how and did it.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group" v-for="(file, i) in registerData.requiredDocuments" :key="`file-${i}`">
            <label for="npwp" class="text-muted"> {{file.name}} </label>
            <input type="file" :ref="'file' + i" :name="file.name" class="form-control-file" :id="file.name"
                :accept="file.name === 'Logo' ? `image/png, image/jpg, image/jpeg` : `application/pdf`">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <button @click.prevent="setFileFocus(i)" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Choose File</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {    
    methods: {
        setFileFocus(index) {
            this.$nextTick(function(){
                this.$refs[("file" + index)][0].focus()
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I called `focus` on `nexttick`. Hope my answer will be helpful

Comment: yup this is exactly what i did but the problem is, the ref is bind to a v-for and the parameter of the loop is undefined

Comment: Yes, I see. I have edited my code snippet. Try it now, it should work